# How do I make a conditional query to a mongodb database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make a filtering component for my website and I want to be able to get that data which they specified through the filter from the MongoDB database. I'm using MERN stack and want to  conditionally send a query to the database to retrieve based on whether or not it's empty or not. If it's empty, it means the user wants anything in that specific category and not one specific thing so I don't want to send an empty query to the DB which is just going to look for an empty string/array and realize that nothing in the DB has an empty string/array and won't return anything.

That's why I want to conditionally render my query parameter because that's the only workaround I can think of for my earlier question which does not have a solution for:
[How can I send an object as a query and use the $all operator in MERN stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73239827/how-can-i-send-an-object-as-a-query-and-use-the-all-operator-in-mern-stack)

Here is the code and where I want the the conditional render to happen:

```
    var t = ["People"]
    const test = await Project.find( {$all: {
        theme: t // have something that condditionally sends this, if t is empty then don't send it
    }}
    ).sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally construct the search-filter:

```
const filter = {};
if (t.length) { // or whatever condition you need
  filter.$all = {theme: t};
}

const test = await Project.find(filter) // rest of your code
```

Comment: I don't really understand how this works `filter.$all = {theme: t}`, if I have more queries, ex `sdg` and `assignment_type`, how would I make separate conditions for those and add it to the filter object? I don't really get what the piece of code I pasted above does, does it add it to the object like this `theme: [filtered data]` or something else?

Comment: Essentially `filter` is just an object, allowing you to add whatever properties you like. For more complex queries where you need to combine multiple conditions, you should take a look at MongoDB's `$and`/`$or` operators.